# Function to save data as struct on C

Tags: c, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

 typedef struct equipamento { 
    int codDipositivo;
    char nomeEquipamento[40];
    char newVar[50];
}Equipamento;

insert(int n, int cat, Equipamento eq[])
{
    int codigo;
    char newVar[40];
    printf("\nNew Var: ");  
    scanf("%s",&newVar);    
    eq[n].codDipositivo=newVar;
}

main()
{
    Equipamento equipamento[MAX_EQ_DSP];


    ...a bunch of scanfs 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&pr);


    insert(n, pr, equipamento);
}
```

This is a sample of what I have.

on **main** I have a bunch of scanfs which will update the data showing on the screen but now I want to pass that data into a structure and ask for additional information.

I'm trying to use the updated code but for some reason, instead of 39 chars, it breaks down (returns to the main cycle) after the first char

```
printf("\nNome do Equipamento: "); 
gets(nome);
strcpy(eq[n].nomeEquipamento, nome);
```

Comment: This questions shows a serious lack of understanding the technology involved and is beyond the scope of SO.  Please refer to an appropriate beginners tutorial and relevant documentation first.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
eq[n].codDipositivo=newVar;
```

In C, you cannot assign arrays, you need to copy them element for element. Remember that C has no string data type, a string is just a NUL-terminated array of char. Luckily there is a function in the C library to help us, `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(eq[n].codDipositivo, newVar);
```

To get the declaration of `strcpy`you need to add the following include at the top of your code:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: @Pedro codDipositivo is int, so you probably meant eq[n].newVar?

Comment: My mistake. But I need both a string and ints from this function

Comment: printf("\nName: "); fgets(name, 4000, stdin);strcpy(eq[n].nomeEquipamento, name);                                I can run this code, but as i enter the first character it breaks the loop and returns to the main menu. Ideas?

Comment: What loop? C only has explicit loops (`for`, `while`).

Comment: I have a **Do While** showing stuff on the screen and a switch to select the menu entry. When I write the first character for fgets it goes back to the menu.....

Comment: The whole code is here: http://pastebin.com/2PL8s4Re just try pressing this key sequence to move on the menu "1 2 1 2 2 x" You should be able to enter 39 characters on x, but it breaks after entering the first one.

Comment: I think you need to add `fflush(stdout);` before each `scanf` where the preceding printf doesn't end with `\n`. `stdout` is line buffered, so without an explicit `fflush` you won't see the last (incomplete) line of output.